# Can I get Old version(Before September, 2015) of 'ARC Welder'?

Tags: automatic-ref-counting

I started Arc Welder to play games, august, 2015.

but you update Arc welder in first, september, 2015, after it, ARC Welder couldn't play game, music-player, etc... How can I?

The APP is Melon(Streaming Music player), Mabinogi Duel(game) of South Korea